# Open "Get Information" Window in Finder by Applescript (Again)

Tags: macos, applescript, finder

There's a question on the site about getting *file* information via script, well answered by regulus6633. The solution provided worked for me on a folder, but I was unable to get it to work similarly on an application file.

```
set aFile to (POSIX file "/Applications/Google Chrome.app") as text
tell application "Finder" to open information window of application aFile
```

The path is correct, insofar as I can tell, but it keeps returning the syntax error:

"Finder got an error: Can’t get application "Macintosh HD:Applications:Google Chrome.app".

(I'm a designer, not a coder, so please excuse if the answer's obvious!)

Comment: Can you post a link to the question and answer that have worked for you? Your question is not quite clear...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You ***almost*** had it right, but "almost" can be frustrating in AppleScript :-)

```
set aFile to (POSIX file "/Applications/Google Chrome.app") as alias
tell application "Finder" to open information window of aFile
```

To get the data, rather than opening the window to look at, use

```
set aFile to (POSIX file "/Applications/Google Chrome.app") as alias
info for aFile
```